# Delete "disconnected" messages that don't have a preceding "has connected." message

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed

I have a long log file and I'm trying to get rid of all lines that contain `foo disconnected` but don't have an accompanying line containing `foo has connected.` that would precede the disconnection message. The tricky part about this is that the file can contain multiple disconnection messages from the same user that DO have preceding connection messages and all of these messages would precede the bugged disconnection message.

For example, from this sample file I would like to remove 4th, 6th and the last 3 lines.

```
user1 has connected.
BigDaddy has connected.
user1 disconnected
foobar123 disconnected
user1 has connected.
noobmaster disconnected
user1 disconnected
BigDaddy disconnected
BigDaddy has connected.
user1 disconnected
user1 disconnected
user1 disconnected
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `awk`, use an array to track which users have active connections.

```
awk '/has conn/ { arr[$1]=1; }
     arr[$1] {print}
     /disconn/ {arr[$1]=0}' tmp.txt
```

Note we check the value of `arr[$1]` *before* disabling it on disconnected lines, so that the first of consecutive lines is still printed.

Comment: The first, most concise and the only answer that worked correctly for me. Thanks!

Comment: This assumes that the `has connected` and `disconnected` messages are the only ones in the log file. It's a strange log file if that's true, and the answer doesn't solve the question *"Delete “disconnected” messages that don't have a preceding “has connected” message"* as a whole lot more is deleted

Comment: It worked for the file I specified. I guess I should have pointed out I actually delete all lines that don't contain either of the two messages since I don't need them for the purpose I need this command. So yes, in my original question the log file is only meant to contain these two messages.

Answer (score 1):

Keep a hash of the users that are connected

This program expected the path to the input log file as a parameter on the command line

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %connected;

while ( <> ) {

    my ($user, $action) = split ' ', $_, 2;

    if ( $action =~ /disconnected/i ) {
        next unless $connected{$user};
        $connected{$user} = 0;
    }
    elsif ( $action =~ /connected/i ) {
        $connected{$user} = 1;
    }

    print;
}
```

#### output

```
user1 has connected.
BigDaddy has connected.
user1 disconnected
user1 has connected.
noobmaster disconnected
BigDaddy has connected.
user1 disconnected
```

---

It's not impossible to write terse incomprehensible code in Perl. Here's a conversion of [the awk solution from chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32210520/622310). It has the same output as above, but note my misgivings in my comment on his solution

```
perl -n -e'
    ($u) = /(\S+)/;
    $arr[$u] = 1 if /has conn/;
    print if $arr[$u];
    $arr[$uarr[$1]] = 0 if /disconn/
' tmp.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my @lines = <DATA>;
my %status = ();
foreach my $line (@lines) {
        my ($user) = $line =~ /([A-Za-z0-9]+)\s+/;
        #User has connected and not defined or disconnected
        if($line =~ /has connected/ && !$status{$user}){
                $status{$user} = 1;
                print $line;
        }
        # Connected user disconnected.
        elsif($line =~ /disconnected/ && $status{$user}){
                $status{$user} = 0;
                print $line;
        }
}
```

Comment: This deletes all the lines I needed but also some other seemingly random connection and disconnection messages.

Answer (score -1):

Using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl):

```
open FILE, "<disconnect.txt" or die $!;
my @lines = <FILE>;
close FILE or die $!;
my @connectedusers = ();

foreach $line(@lines) {
    # if connected, then push user name to array
    if($line =~ /(\w+) has connected/) {
        push(@connectedusers, $1);
        print $line;
    # if disconnected, then check whether user name is in array
    } elsif ($line =~ /(\w+) disconnected/) {
        my $idx = 0;
        foreach(@connectedusers) {
            if(/$1/) {
                # remove user name from array
                splice(@connectedusers, $idx, 1);
                print $line;
            }
            $idx++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This deletes all the lines I needed but also some other disconnection messages and duplicates some other seemingly random disconnection messages.

Comment: This breaks many rules of best-practice Perl. The most senior of which is that you ***must always*** `use strict` and `use warnings`; without the former there's little point in declaring stuff with `my`. In addition, you should also *use lexical file handles* and the *three-argument `open`*. It is always best to use `while ( <$fh> ) { ... }` rather than your `@lines = <$fh>; for ( @lines ) { ... }`. You also have a logic error in that `$1` is set by the latest successfuly-matching regex, so the first time `if ( /$1/ ) { ... }` succeeds it will undefine `$1` because there are no captures